# Application package installation com.apple.installer.pagecontroller erreur -1

Tags: objective-c

I have an objective-c application developped with Xcode 4.2.1. and I failed to get the application package (Archive/share/Mac OSX App Store Package (.pkg).
I opened a new "test" project, archived and shared it as a test.pkg and get 2 kinds of error :
1 If I attempt to open the package on my MAC running Lion (the one where Xcode is running), I have an alert : "test.pkg can't be installed on this computer".
2 If I attempt to open the package on another MAC running Leopard, I have an error message :
test.pkg can't be opened
Installation problem
com.apple.installer.pagecontroller erreur -1 
It is the .pkg which is the problem because It OK for "share/Application".
I have not yet opened my developer account and don't know if an account is required to create a package.
It is my first objective-c application and any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a developer account and get certificates to sign the package.